# In Tolkien's own visual art, why is it that Bag End has no visible chimneys?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, books, art

I asked this question of Wayne Hammond years ago, after going through *J. R. R. Tolkien: Artist and Illustrator*. He didn't know. I also asked about having to go and he speculatively joked about going round the back of the big tree. But seriously, the fireplace at Bag End is all over the text and plays a key role in important ways, but Tolkien never depicts its chimney in his art? Where is it?

Comment: There is a vertical pencil squiggle on *Bag End Underhill* which could possibly be interpreted as chimney smoke. Not sure.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVSwN.png - Squiggle

Comment: @Valorum - Yeah, that one. Also it's not as clear in that reproduction, but the squiggle is part of the pencil layer and is not part of the ink layer.

Comment: Opinion without sources: hills look worse with chimneys. Also, Tolkien probably never gave any thought to how the outside must look based on the inside. He was a linguist, not an architect. No one is an expert at everything.

Comment: I would expect hobbits to simply use holes. Why build a chimney?

Comment: @MichaelFoster As a linguist, Tolkien could simply translate "fireplace" from English to Spanish and back again, and presto!  He's got a chimney.